# How do I resolve the compilation error "Unpin not implemented for GenFuture" resulting from adapting a stream using a combinator?

Tags: rust

I'm unable to work out how to resolve the compilation error resulting from adapting a stream using a combinator.

The following [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da4a3e17f6ae5721cf8a341f75889c97) demonstrates a fairly minimal example:

```
use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::StreamExt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Input {
    A,
    B(i32),
    C(u16),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Output {
    Int(i32),
    Short(u16),
}

pub struct StreamMaker;

impl StreamMaker {
    /// make a stream with a series of inputs
    pub fn create(self) -> impl Stream<Item = Input> {
        stream::iter(vec![Input::A, Input::C(1u16), Input::B(2)])
    }
}

/// consume the creator, and make output messages for a subset
pub fn adapt_stream(creator: StreamMaker) -> impl Stream<Item = Output> {
    let mut upstream = creator.create();
    upstream.filter_map(|message| async move {
        match message {
            Input::A => None,
            Input::B(v) => Some(Output::Int(v)),
            Input::C(v) => Some(Output::Short(v)),
        }
    })
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    let creator = StreamMaker {};
    let mut stream = adapt_stream(creator);

    while let Some(message) = stream.next().await {
        println!("message: {:?}", message)
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:29:46: 35:6 message:Input {}]>: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied in `impl core::future::future::Future`
  --> src/main.rs:43:38
   |
43 |     while let Some(message) = stream.next().await {
   |                                      ^^^^ within `impl core::future::future::Future`, the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:29:46: 35:6 message:Input {}]>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::future::GenFuture<T> as std::marker::Unpin>
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Unpin` for `futures_util::stream::stream::filter_map::FilterMap<impl futures_core::stream::Stream, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:29:25: 35:6]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl futures_core::stream::Stream`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:29:46: 35:6 message:Input {}]>: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied in `impl core::future::future::Future`
  --> src/main.rs:43:31
   |
43 |     while let Some(message) = stream.next().await {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ within `impl core::future::future::Future`, the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:29:46: 35:6 message:Input {}]>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::future::GenFuture<T> as std::marker::Unpin>
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Unpin` for `futures_util::stream::stream::filter_map::FilterMap<impl futures_core::stream::Stream, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:29:25: 35:6]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl futures_core::stream::Stream`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `core::future::future::Future` for `futures_util::stream::stream::next::Next<'_, impl futures_core::stream::Stream>`
```

I can put a `pin_mut!(stream);` in the main, but I'd like to be able to push that upstream.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not want the consumer of your stream to have to pin it themselves, you need to return a stream that implements the `Unpin` trait, meaning that it is safe to move around in memory even after is has been pinned.

```rust
pub fn adapt_stream(creator: StreamMaker) -> impl Stream<Item = Output> + Unpin {
//                                                      add Unpin trait --^
```

Adding this, your compiler should complain that the return value doesn't implement `Unpin`. This is because `async move { ... }` blocks don't implement `Unpin`, since they may be self-referential (e.g. contain references to variables they own). The most general way to work around this is to pin the stream to the heap with a `Pin<Box<_>>`, using the `Box::pin` constructor:

```rust
pub fn adapt_stream(creator: StreamMaker) -> impl Stream<Item = Output> + Unpin {
    let mut upstream = creator.create();
    Box::pin(upstream.filter_map(|message| async move {
//  ^-- pin stream to heap
        match message {
            Input::A => None,
            Input::B(v) => Some(Output::Int(v)),
            Input::C(v) => Some(Output::Short(v)),
        }
    }))
}
```

Since we're now returning a `Pin<Box<_>>` pointer to the stream, that pointer can be safely moved around in memory while the inner stream is kept at the same location.

[Full playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bc6fe287197e46084c8d43c5c107452f)